# How to implement avy comment region function?

Tags: evil, text-editing, avy

I am using doom emacs on Mac OS. I would like to have an avy comment region and line command, where just as with for example `avy-kill-region` the region is selected. I've come up with the following function

```
(defun my-avy-comment-region ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
     
    (let* ((eol (pos-eol))
           (beg (avy--line))
           (end (avy--line)))
(evilnc-comment-operator beg end )
      )))
```

which does exactly what I want except the endline seems to be one line off from the selected. How can I modify the code, so I am selecting the right line with `avy--line` for the end?
Analogously I would like to implement `my-avy-comment-line` function where I struggle to parse the end of the line, so this would also be nice to full functionability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefer using Emacs native functions over evil functions, if possible.

Additionally, as you've mentioned, there is already `avy-kill-region`. I would reuse it with as little modification as possible. So you can just replace the `cond` clauses with the 'kill functions', with `comment-region`.

`avy--line` gives you the start position of the line, and it seems like `comment-region` and apparently also `(evilnc-comment-operator beg end)` don't include that line when commenting. So, then just try to take the start position of the next line. In summary, the following code (adapted from `avi-kill-region`, please diff the two functions to see the differences) should achieve what you want:

```lisp
(defun avy-comment-region (arg)
  "Comment the region starting end ending with selected lines.

The window scope is determined by `avy-all-windows' or
`avy-all-windows-alt' when ARG is non-nil."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((initial-window (selected-window)))
    (avy-with avy-kill-region
      (let* ((beg (save-selected-window
                    (list (avy--line arg) (selected-window))))
             (end (list
                   (save-excursion
                     (goto-char (avy--line arg))
                     (forward-line)
                     (point))
                     (selected-window))))
        (cond
          ((not (numberp (car beg)))
           (user-error "Fail to select the beginning of region"))
          ((not (numberp (car end)))
           (user-error "Fail to select the end of region"))
          ;; Restrict operation to same window. It's better if it can be
          ;; different windows but same buffer; however, then the cloned
          ;; buffers with different narrowed regions might cause problem.
          ((not (equal (cdr beg) (cdr end)))
           (user-error "Selected points are not in the same window"))
          (t
           (save-excursion
             (comment-region (car beg) (car end)))))))
    (select-window initial-window)))
```

Of course, instead of finding the next line, you could just remember to select the line after the region you'd like to comment (and keep the `avi-kill-region` functionality/definition that it acts on the region 'between the selected lines).

Comment: Why are emacs native functions preferable? Do they execute faster, or what are the main arguments? Could you also provide what should be different for avy-comment-line? I would accept the answer.

Comment: Good question. Indeed, preferring Emacs functions is a personal rule, it makes code more portable, and you can generally be sure that the Emacs functions are well designed. If you find a problem with a function, you can report a bug directly to Emacs, instead of to some external package. But, for personal use, you can use any function that does the job (but obviously, personally, I prefer to follow my personal rule).

Comment: To modify the code to `avy-comment-line` you simply replace the `(avy--line arg)` in `end` with `(cdr beg)` (try to understand why this change works ;).